# Python print scraped data with beautifulsoup without tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
<div class="number" title="Player number">1211</div>
<div class="shirt" title="sName">Ronaldo 1211</div>
```

I'm scraping a website. I've managed to print out the . Here is my code:

```
web = urllib2.urlopen("WEBSITE")
soupit = BeautifulSoup(web, 'html.parser')
scrapeme = soupit.findAll("div", { "class" : "number" })
print scrapeme
```

prints out :

```
<div class="id" title="Player number">1211</div>
```

I want it to print just the 1211. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`get_ text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method of any beautifulsoup object does exactly that.

```
print(scrapeme.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your list of elements, `scrapeme`, you can loop through each element in the list and print it's text attribute using:

```
for element in scrapeme:
    print(element.text)
```

Since in your example the scrape only generates a list `scrapeme` containing one element, the output in this case will just be:

```
1211
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a doumentation that explains what the .text function does exactly?

Comment: Try searching for 'text' here http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/